# Existence of a particular complex atlas (and nested precompact sets)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a complex topological manifold. Can I always find an atlas $A=\{\psi_i:{U_i\rightarrow V_i\subseteq \mathbb{C},i\in \mathbb{N}}\}$ so that $U_i\subseteq U_{i+1}$ (with $\{U_i\}$ an open cover of $X$, of course) and $V_i$ is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$  for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$?

Since each $\psi_i$ is bicontinuous, hence proper (preimage of compact sets being compact), and compact sets are equivalent to closed and bounded sets in $\mathbb{C}$, wouldn't this imply that, with $\overline{V_i}$ being closed and bounded, hence compact, (necessarily nested) subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, $\psi_i^{-1}(\overline{V_i})=\overline{U_i}$ are compact? How would I modify this construction to get a sequence of precompact $U_i$ with $\overline{U_i}\subseteq{U_{i+1}}$?

Comment: What is a complex topological manifold? It seems that it is the same as a topological two-dimensional real manifold.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for checking in. By complex topological manifold, I mean a one-dimensional complex manifold: a topological space locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. You could think of it as a two-dimensional real manifold.

Answer (score 1):

A complex topological manifold $M$ is a space locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb C$, or equivalently a two-dimensional real manifold.

Consider the torus $T = S^1 \times S^1$ which is a a two-dimensional real manifold. If it had an atlas as in your question (without any requirements on the $V_i$), then by compactness you would find $n$ such that $U_n = T$. Hence there would be an embedding $\psi : T \to \mathbb C$ which is impossible.

Concerning your question, let me remark that $\psi_i^{-1}(\overline{V_i})=\overline{U_i}$ does not make sense. In fact, $\psi_i^{-1}$ is only defined on $V_i$.

Finally, the charts $\psi : U \to V \subset \mathbb C$ such that $V$ is bounded *always* form an atlas. In fact, if $x \in M$ and $\psi$ is a chart around $x$, then $\psi \mid_U' : U' \to V'$ with $V' = U_{\lvert \psi(x) \rvert+1}(\psi(x)) \cap V$ and $U' = \psi^{-1}(V')$ is again a chart around around $x$ and $V'$ is bounded.